# Is "Why wouldn't I want to do X?" is on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Here is the full text of the question I was planning to ask, not just a one-line summary of it:

> In my daily work, I work several problems concurrently, and each
>   problem has its own sandbox folder:
>
> ```
> $ ls ~/work
> problem0  problem1  problem2  problem3  problem4  problem5  problem6
> ```
>
> Most, if not all of these folders have copies of the same Python
>   sources in various states of revision.  When working a particular
>   problem, I absolutely do not want my Python `import` statements to
>   find the Python sources that correspond to a *different problem*.
>
> My solution thus far has been to put a shell script into each sandbox
>   folder to `export PYTHONPATH` accordingly.  I then (try to) remember
>   to `source` this bash script prior to beginning work in that sandbox.
>
> This solution has its drawbacks.  The most obvious drawback being that
>   I can forget to `source` the script.  Creating a new script for every
>   problem start is also somewhat tedious.  The existence of other
>   developers compounds the problem.
>
> Then, a thought occurred to me.  When `__name__` == `__main__`, I know
>   that my Python program is being invoked as script (not imported as a
>   library) and I should have all the knowledge required to fully
>   configure `sys.path` based on the path of the Python source file
>   itself.
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     import inspect
>     thisFilePath = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentFrame())
>     # Assign sys.path relative to thisFilePath!
> ```
>
> If all of my Python programs did this thing, I could invoke them
>   blindly, without having to `export PYTHONPATH`, and without worrying
>   about `sys.path` being 'contaminated' with folders that don't belong.
>
> So, why wouldn't I do this?  What could go wrong?  Also, what are the
>   relative merits/demirits of this approach when compared to wrapping
>   every single Python program with a sh/bat pair that configures
>   `PYTHONPATH` accordingly?  What are other people doing?

Comment: Blatantly _too broad_!

Comment: "What could go wrong" is definitely broad.  Where did you hear this advice, and what led you to asking this question to begin with?  We could salvage this sort of thing if you give a specific use case for it.

Comment: Maybe your questions is "What is the drawback of configuring sys.path when ...." and include your findings, ie. have you actually done it and you didn't see any immediate adverse effects?

Comment: @Braiam, Yes, I have done this thing and it seems to have no immediate adverse effects.  My concerns are that the approach may be poor practice or a known anti-pattern to be avoided.

Comment: And now, my question on meta is downvoted as inappropriate for meta?  Weird.

Comment: @DavidCharles You could have done a bit of research in the help center, such is required here, as at any SE site as well.#

Comment: @DavidCharles Fortunately my answer still stands after your radical edit.

Comment: @DavidCharles I'm qualifying by the last paragraph in your question mainly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to narrow down or at least quantify the problem so that it's not incredibly broad.  As you describe it, your mode of operation includes you importing a script that is in several different, varying states, and you don't want those states to collide.

Would the better question be, "How would I ensure that by doing this, the `PYTHONPATH` remains stable, since I have a feeling that this may introduce instability?"

From what I can tell, the *only* thing that's triggering an immediate "too broad" reaction is the open-ended phrasing of your question towards the end.  If you revise *that*, this question could be alright.

Also, considering that there are other, and likely better ways to go about doing this, I see some value in this question, since this is honestly the first time I've heard of someone doing Python in this very strange fashion.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response.  Would a better question be: What is the best way to enable a user to fetch a blob of Python code from revision control and run it without configuring `PYTHONPATH`?  (a) Wrap each Python program in a sh/bat launcher that sets PYTHONPATH; (b) Have each Python program configure `sys.path` internally; (c) Don't try to fix this problem---you will make things worse; (d) Something else entirely?

Comment: @DavidCharles Questions that involve "best, worst, industry standard" etc are almost certainly opinion based. A good litmus test is to ask yourself if that question could be answered by anyone and still _technically_ be correct because you asked for what was _best_ which is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Ares OK, take out the word 'best'?  How to enable a user to fetch a blob of Python code from revision control and run it without configuring `PYTHONPATH`?  And, here are the things I have tried, and why I have misgivings about them.

Comment: And there we go! By my assessment, if you were to do all those things, you would have an excellent question. I can't speak for the whole of SO but that seems good to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this type of "what-could-go-wrong" question considered on-topic for stackoverflow?

No, it's definitely *too broad*, or even *opinion based* (depends a bit on formulation).

Such kind of questions are *off-topic*, and it's actually mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> > Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be [put on hold by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) until they are improved.

Comment: Thank you for informing me that my question is "definitely too broad or even opinion based".  While I can read these words in the help center, it was unclear to me that they applied to my type of question.

Comment: @DavidCharles I feel your pain.

Comment: @DavidCharles What did your _rubber duck_ tell  you, when you've been asking it? :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, I do not follow your question about the *rubber duck*.

Comment: @DavidCharles Did you ever hear about [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? I meant to use a bit of extrapolation here.

Comment: It's not that I disagree that this question is off topic in its current state, but honestly, it's not as bad as any of the other questions I've seen here.  Waving them off doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @Makoto Well my answer was written as a response to the very 1st version of this question. Did you see it?

Comment: I did, and I also commented on it.  In most of the cases, the generic answer can help, but in *this* case, an opportunity to help someone better formulate a specific question exists, which is why I don't feel that waving them off and tacitly considering it off-topic is not all that helpful.

Comment: @Makoto Okey :) ...